# Is there a setting that I can configure to hide activity bar when executing Python script in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know it is a default behavior when you executing a Python script in VS Code, the activity bar will expand. Is there a setting where I can turn that behavior off? I have searched pretty much all the posts and Google, so far have not found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```json
"debug.openDebug": "neverOpen",
```